# SQL Like Operator very slow when using from Another table in AWS Athena

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, sql-like, amazon-athena

I have SQL query in athena that is very slow when using like operator value from another table

```
Select * from table1 t1
Where t1.value like (select 
concat('%',t2.value,'%') as val 
from table2 t2 where t2.id =1 
limit 1)
```

The above query is very slow

When i am using something like below query its working super fast

```
Select * from table1 t1
Where t1.value like 
'%somevalue%'
```

In my scenario the like value is not fixed it can be changed by the time that's why i need to use this value from another table.

Please suggest fastest way

Comment: You have no ordering criteria so your select from t2 is essentially random; your query is not correlated so do you see any improvement if you first select the value from t2 into a variable and use that for your like criteria?

Comment: Using the `LIKE` operator in SQL for anything except a prefix search will always be slow because it has to read and compare against _every_ value in the table - and because database servers cannot (currently, generally) index strings for arbitrary substring searches like that. If you need to do full-text searches then you'll need a full-text search engine like Lucene or any full-text search functionality provided by the DBMS'  - I'm unfamiliar with Athena so don't know what Athena offers in that space.

Comment: Stu the problem is that Athena does not support variable like SQL server

Comment: Dai when providing direct string its very fast, when getting value from other it went slow i don't know why its happening

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know Athena so really just offering best guesses for what I know might help on other platforms; another guess would be can you try refactoring it to use a CTE, or *joining*  to subquery with like condition as join criteria? Somehow you need to force the query optimizer to generate the same plan as for the string literal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have found other method to the same and it's super faster in Athena

```
Select * from table1 t1
Where POSITION ( (select concat('%',t2.value,'%') as val from table2 t2 where t2.id =1 limit 1) in t1.value   )>0
```

Answer (score 0):

"Slow" is a relative term, but a query that joins two tables will always be *slower* than a query that doesn't. A query that compares against a pattern that needs to be looked up in another table at query time will always be *slower* than a query that uses a static pattern.

Does that mean that the second query is slow? Perhaps, but it you have to base that on what you're actually asking the query engine to do.

Let's dissect what your query is doing:

- The outer query looks for all columns of all rows of the first table where one of the columns contains a particular string.
- That string is dynamically looked up by *scanning every row in the second table* looking for a row with a particular value for the `id` column.

In other words, the first query scans only the first table but the second scans both tables. That's always going to be slower, because it's doing a lot more work. How much more work? That depends on the sizes of the tables. You aren't specifying the running times of any of the queries or the sizes of the tables, so it's hard to know.

You don't provide enough context in your question to answer any more precise than this. We can only respond with generalities like: if it's slow then don't use `LIKE`, that's a slow operation. Don't do a correlated subquery that reads the whole second table, that's slow.

Comment: i have found other method to the same and it's super faster in Athena

Select * from table1 t1
Where POSITION ( (select concat('%',t2.value,'%') as val from table2 t2 where t2.id =1 limit 1) in t1.value   )>0